# Tailwind not getting applied --npx build command generating broken css file

Tags: css, node.js, express, styles, tailwind-css

I am running following command, which is generating broken style.css, due to which tailwind css doesn't gets apply to views (I am using node/express js). Could anybody please help why this is happening.

```
npm build:css
```

package.json (sample extract)

```
 {

 "build:css": "npx tailwindcss-cli@latest build -i  ./public/stylesheets/tailwind.css -o ./public/stylesheets/style.css"
}
```

style.css start with below part

```
        /*! tailwindcss v2.2.19 | MIT License | https://tailwindcss.com */

    /*! modern-normalize v1.1.0 | MIT License | https://github.com/sindresorhus/modern-normalize */

    /*
    Document
    ========
    */

    /**
    Use a better box model (opinionated).
    */

    *,
    ::before,
    ::after {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use firefox, you can reload the css, by holding the shift key when you refresh it.

Comment: the css which is getting generated is broken one, I am running this command from VS code terminal. This issue is not ocurring during pageload or page referesh.  npm build:css

Comment: please expand more, what do you mean broken?